# login and signup in android using php database present in a server

Tags: php, android

App stops responding when i click submit and login button in both login and signup activity.i retrieve data from a table named user_details.i have made two php files signupapp.php and loginapp.php to make this happen but still cant get my app functioning.Please help
login.java

```
package secondslash.secondslash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button login, sign_up;
    TextView welcome, welcome2,error;
    EditText loginid, password;
    String email, pwd, pwd1;
    public final static boolean validation(CharSequence ch)
    {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(ch))
    {
        return false;
    }
        else
        {
        return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(ch).matches();
        }
    }
    public static boolean isValidEmail(String target)
    {
        return target.contains("@");
      //  return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        welcome2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
        loginid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        error= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            error.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            login.setEnabled(false);
            sign_up.setEnabled(false);
            loginid.setEnabled(false);
            password.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }


        public void login(View view) {

                email=loginid.getText().toString();
                pwd=password.getText().toString();
                String method = "Login";
               BackgroundTask backgroundTask= new BackgroundTask(this);
                backgroundTask.execute(method,email,pwd);
           // finish();
                    Intent i = new Intent(
                            login.this,
                            secondslash.secondslash.premain.class
                    );
                    startActivity(i);};

        public void signup(View view)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, signup.class));
        }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

signup.java

```
package secondslash.secondslash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class signup extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button next;
   public TextView Email,Pwd,Pwd1,Fname,Lname;


    String email,pwd,fname,lname,pwd1;
    String stringarray[];
    TextView login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);
        Pwd1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SUpwdconf);
        Fname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SUfname);
        Lname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SUlname);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SUnext);
        Email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SUemail_id);
        Pwd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SUpwd);
        login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlogin);}


    public void register(View view) {

        email = Email.getText().toString();
        pwd = Pwd.getText().toString();
        fname = Fname.getText().toString();
        lname = Lname.getText().toString();
        pwd1 = Pwd1.getText().toString();
        String method = "signup";
        BackgroundTask bTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        bTask.execute(method,fname, lname, email, pwd);
        finish();
    }


    public void login1(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, login.class));
    }


  /*  class backgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String add_info_url;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            add_info_url = "secondslash.site88.net/signupapp.php";
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String fname, email, lname, pwd;
            fname = args[0];
            lname = args[1];
            email = args[2];
            pwd = args[3];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(add_info_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String data_string = URLEncoder.encode("firstname", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(fname, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("lastname", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lname, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pwd, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data_string);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Sign up successful";

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }*/


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_signup, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

backgroundtask.java

```
package secondslash.secondslash;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

/**
 * Created by alokit nigam on 11/29/2015.
 */
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context ctx;
AlertDialog alertD;
   public BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
      this.ctx=ctx;
   }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String signup_url="http://secondslash.site88.net/signupapp.php";
        String login_url="http://secondslash.site88.net/loginapp.php";
        String method=params[0];
        if(method.equals("signup"))
        {
            String fname=params[1];
            String lname=params[2];
            String email=params[3];
            String pwd=params[4];

            try {
                URL url=new URL(signup_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data_string= URLEncoder.encode("firstname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(fname,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("lastname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(lname,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pwd,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data_string);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Sign Up Succesful";

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("Login"))
        {
            String email=params[1];
            String pwd=params[2];
            try {
                URL url=new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data_string= URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pwd,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data_string);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputstream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response="";
                String line="";
                while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    response+= line;


                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputstream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertD = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertD.setTitle("Login Info...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

           if(result.equals("Sign Up Succesful"))
           {
               Toast.makeText(ctx,result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
        else
           {
               alertD.setMessage(result);
               alertD.show();
           }
    }
}
```

signupapp.php

```
<?php

    require"init.php";



    $fname=$_POST["firstname"];
    $lname=$_POST["lastname"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    $sql_query="insert into user_details values('$NULL','$fname','$lname','$email','$password','NULL','NULL','NULL');";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
    {
        //echo"<h3>data insertion success</h3>";
    }
    else{
    //  echo"Data insertion error ".mysqli_error($con);
    }
    ?>


loginapp.php
<?php
require"init.php"
$email="alokit@gmail.com";
$password="anigam";
$query="select firstname from user_details where email_id like '$email' and password like '$password';";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $name=$row["firstname"];
    echo"<h3>Hello welcome".$name."</h3>";
}
else{
    echo"not available";
}
?>
```

init.php

```
<?php

$con = @mysqli_connect('mysql1.000webhost.com', 'a7130562_slash', '2slash','a7130562_slash');
if(!$con)
{
    //echo"connection  error".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{

    //echo"<h3> database con success</h3>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> App stops responding when i click submit and login button in both login and signup activity.

I don't think I can see where you handle your Button click events in both login.java and signup.java using `setOnClickListener()`